# convert the code of c# into tcl how to create this array or whatever it is and the how to apply if condition'

Tags: tcl

convert the code given below into tcl :-

```c#
ReportLog("\nCheck 4th and 5th TLPs.");
UInt32[] tlp4 = new UInt32[4];
UInt32[] tlp5 = new UInt32[4];
captureMemory.GetTlp(3, tlp4);
captureMemory.GetTlp(4, tlp5);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (tlp4[i] != tlp5[i])
    {
        ReportLog("\nRetry buffer not persistent through link recovery. Test failed.");
        ReportResult(ETestResultCode.RESULT_ERROR, "Retry buffer not persistent through link recovery. Test failed.");
        return 1;
    }
```

here value `new UInt32[4]` is being filled from some other function......
 mainly i ma confused in how to write the part given below....

```c#
UInt32[] tlp4 = new UInt32[4];
UInt32[] tlp5 = new UInt32[4];
captureMemory.GetTlp(3, tlp4);
captureMemory.GetTlp(4, tlp5);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (tlp4[i] != tlp5[i])
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

Tcl manages memory and numbers in a *totally* different way to C#. That changes what might be the right approach quite a bit. However, we might want the interface to be something like this:

```tcl
set tlp4 [lrepeat 4 0]; # Have to specify the default value; C# just uses 0 anyway.
set tlp5 [lrepeat 4 0]

# These lines might vary quite a bit; the code in question isn't standard Tcl
# Note that we're passing the variable *names* in.
captureMemory getTlp 3 tlp4
captureMemory getTlp 4 tlp5

# Foreach can iterate over multiple lists at once; this is *NICE*
foreach element4 $tlp4 element5 $tlp5 {
    if {$element4 != $element5} {
        # Do the error handling...
```

A messier but somewhat more direct approach is to use byte arrays.

```tcl
set tlp4 [binary format "iu4" {0 0 0 0}]
set tlp5 [binary format "iu4" {0 0 0 0}]

captureMemory getTlp 3 tlp4
captureMemory getTlp 4 tlp5

# Convert to lists
binary scan $tlp4 "iu4" uints4
binary scan $tlp5 "iu4" uints5

foreach element4 $uints4 element5 $uints5 {
    if {$element4 != $element5} {
        # Do the error handling...
```

Note that the `iu4` format string (for 4 unsigned integers, each of size 4 bytes) is only supported from Tcl 8.6 onwards. With older versions, you'll need to use `i4` and handle the fact that the values are signed.

Also, if you're *just* comparing the values, you can just use string equality between `$tlp4` and `$tlp5` directly.